# How to create virtual machine using v2 of Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using v2 of Azure API. Which scope should be used on authorization for creating virtual machine later?
For the v1 I was using https://management.core.windows.net and it worked, however I need a sign-in for any microsoft account and have to use v2 for this, but using the same scope (https://management.core.windows.net) is invalid for v2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right you cant do any operation without signing in into your account in V1. For this you need to configure your account in active directly and give its values directly in your method and this will return you a token and from that token you have to initialize your class like this here `Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx", accessToken)` and then you can perform any operation like you want to create virtual machine or you want to create a sql server on virtual machine. Here is the code for creating a token.

```
`public AuthenticationResult GetAccessToken()
    {
        string hardcodedUsername = "activedirectoryusername";
        string hardcodedPassword = "activedirectorypassword";

        string tenant = "abc.onmicrosoft.com";
        string clientId = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string resourceHostUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        string aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
        //string aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize";

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(aadInstance, tenant));
        UserCredential userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(hardcodedUsername, hardcodedPassword);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceHostUri, clientId, userCredential).Result;

        return authenticationResult;
    }`
```

Your user of active directory should be minimum role of member to do operations.